# Sql query empty result on php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$publication_year = $_GET['publication_year'];
$conn = db_connect('guest');
```

....

```
<?php

$query='SELECT DISTINCT publication_id FROM publications ';
if(isset($keyword_label) && isset($publication_year)){
    $query.=' WHERE (publication_key_1="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_2="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_3="'.$keyword_label.'" OR 
    publication_key_4="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_5="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_6="'.$keyword_label.'" OR
    publication_key_7="'.$keyword_label.'") AND publication_year="'.$publication_year.'"';
}
else if(isset($publication_year)){
    $query.=' WHERE publication_year="'.$publication_year.'"';
}
else if(isset($keyword_label)){
    $query.='WHERE publication_key_1="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_2="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_3="'.$keyword_label.'" OR 
    publication_key_4="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_5="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_6="'.$keyword_label.'" OR
    publication_key_7="'.$keyword_label.'"';
}
$query.=' ORDER BY publication_year DESC';

$result = $conn->query($query);
if(!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

returns on my website

`Could not run query:`

without getting the exact error.

Of course I get an empty result if I do not debug it.

Can you tell me why is this happening?

I am LAMP stack(apache 2.2.2. , MySQL client version: 5.5.32 , PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) ) and phpmyadmin where I loaded my ready mysql code that is functional except this.

Running the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT publication_id
FROM publications
ORDER BY publication_year DESC
```

works just fine and returns the results.

Comment: Please show your complete query. What happens if you run the query in PHPadmin? Does it give any results?

Comment: question updates with all the extra information needed. thanks.

Comment: echo out the variable $query and and try it in myPhp admin , what happens then

Comment: which query or if statment you expect to run ?

Comment: if you say you get results in phpmyadmin, this means your query is ok and your php has problems. Try to debug your php code line by line until yo find your problem.

Comment: I am trying to query the $query='SELECT DISTINCT publication_id FROM publications WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY publication_year DESC'

Comment: @GeorgeKourouleas is ^ that what echo's out can you run a simple 
"select * form publications" in your php and get a result ?

Comment: @mcgrailm Yes, in phpmyadmin this query returns results. So, my php has problems, probably the connection with the Database. Except for the code, could it be something else wrong?

Comment: Any other technical error I might fell into? Can you think of something, code aside please?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $query='SELECT DISTINCT publication_id FROM publications WHERE 1=1 ';
 if(isset($keyword_label) && isset($publication_year)){
 $query.=' AND (publication_key_1="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_2="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_3="'.$keyword_label.'" OR 
publication_key_4="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_5="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_6="'.$keyword_label.'" OR
publication_key_7="'.$keyword_label.'") AND publication_year="'.$publication_year.'"';
}
if(isset($publication_year)){
$query.=' AND publication_year="'.$publication_year.'"';
}
if(isset($keyword_label)){
$query.=' AND publication_key_1="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_2="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_3="'.$keyword_label.'" OR 
publication_key_4="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_5="'.$keyword_label.'" OR publication_key_6="'.$keyword_label.'" OR
publication_key_7="'.$keyword_label.'"';
}
$query.=' ORDER BY publication_year DESC';
```

EDIT:

try change this

```
   if(!$result) {
```

to this

```
  if( $result == false ) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still got 'Could not run query:' result after adding the last 4 lines.

Comment: I tried that. I still get the same message. I got more code after that, but the error is here I think. Maybe the connection with the database?

Comment: yes look for connection , try to make error message `if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}`

Comment: I did that and i added an `else { printf("Connect OK:"); }` 
And it returns 'Connect OK', so it is not the connection's issue.

Comment: you sure you have values in `$keyword_label` and other variables ? echo them before the query and see.

Comment: Yes, I just checked it again.