# Error when importing sql database from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So, I export an SQL database from another pc that hosts my website(sucessfully appearing the tab of the site that is responsible for the sql table).

But on my pc, I cannot get it to work. So it got to be a configurations error, something to do with privileges, or the sql database file.

When I import a Database from phpmyadmin for hosting my website I get this error.

```
CREATE DATABASE `information_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

SO, I go and delete the line

```
 CREATE DATABASE `information_schema` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

The DataBases however are being imported and they have the necessary data in them. But, I go on deleting all the imported Databases except information_schema, phpmyadmin and mysql who I cannot delete.

I load my Database again without this line and this time a get this error :

```
Error

SQL query:

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `CHARACTER_SETS`
--
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `CHARACTER_SETS` (
`CHARACTER_SET_NAME` varchar( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME` varchar( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`DESCRIPTION` varchar( 60 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`MAXLEN` bigint( 3 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE = MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

THis sql Database is 2.9 MB so in order to import it, I zip it and import it as a compressed .zip file.

This question is a followup from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979274/sql-query-empty-result-on-php-code) question, when I realized that my problem is not on the php code as it works on another pc by another person(with whom I do not have contact with).

Thanks in advance.

PS: I performed those as well. The problem remains.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Check your user permission on mysql.

Comment: updated question. privileges are 'ALL PRIVILEGES' on my database in phpmyadmin.

Comment: The MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA database is a system database. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html

Comment: So basically you would have to remove the DB  from the import script

Comment: And what about mysql and phpmyadmin? What about those 2 DBs? Should I remove them as well? Because if not, I get a similar error.

Comment: Just import what ever DB where you have information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the "mysql" database, this contains MySQL accounts and privileges information. So you should not import this, however it may contain a MYSQL account necessary for your application. About the "phpmyadmin" database, this contains the phpMyAdmin configuration storage and I suggest to not import it because it's too specific to the original host.

Comment: In addition to what Marc said, you seem to have deleted the line to create the information_schema database, but you're still trying to create the tables. I'd suggest going back to the original database and exporting only the databases you need rather than everything.

Comment: I had this same issue and while the answer above is correct, it wasn't really clear to me. Make sure you DO NOT import the information_schema table is what they are saying.